# PHP session is empty even when Session ID is right

Tags: php, ajax, flash, session

Yesterday I searched almost all topics about php sessions, I looked over manual and it still didn't work. I stayed up very late because of that.

Scenario is: I log in using standard html form. My session is populated with some variables and it work fine. Then I use Flash `uploadify` to upload some photos and I pass with parametrs - `PHPSESSID`. My php script does not recognize session. It sees it as empty. Then I try to get that session with different client such as `Firefox` or `Opera` and it is empty too. Then I try to get that session with different `Chrome` tab and **it works**

As you see my only protection is by IP. I don't scan other things so this **should work** when good PHPSESSID is passed and client IP is matching regardless of client type, version etc.

This is `init_session.php`, file I include everytime at the begining of other files. Therefore I know that Session ID is beeing passed with Flash. But then session is empty.

Directory is set on the top, and path is direct so there shouldn't be any problems with that. It also doesn't work when save path is default. I also turned of session autostart and session use only cookies. It didn't change a thing except I need to set cookie manually.

Is there something here I can try? I think I ran out of options.

EDIT:
**I forgot about most importat thing i think that turning off `suhosin.session.cryptua` will resolve case but i can't turn it off using ini_set, is there any other way?** It seems that this option encrypts session using user-agent field wich would be the case.

```
ini_set('session.auto_start', '0');
ini_set('session.save_path','/public_html/nowy/tmp');

if (isset($_POST["PHPSESSID"])) {
    session_id($_POST["PHPSESSID"]);
} elseif (isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) {
    session_id($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]);
} elseif (isset($_GET["PHPSESSID"])) {
    session_id($_GET["PHPSESSID"]);
} 
session_start();
setcookie("PHPSESSID", session_id(), time()+3600, "/");

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
$_SESSION['user'] = 0;
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['initiate'])) {
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['initiate'] = true;
    $_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

echo ini_get('session.save_path').'<br />';

echo $_POST["PHPSESSID"];
print_r($_SESSION);
```

**RESOLVED**

**This problem has been solved. I couldn't set `cryptua` off because I needed to copy oryginal `php5.ini` and replace some variables to get it working.**

**The problem was as expected `suhosin.session.cryptua`**

Comment: well ... can you initialize a session when you just focus on the technically necessary basics? If yes, then describe the symptoms without all that fog and if no, then try to add one technichal detail after the other until the problem reappears.

Comment: What are the differences between a normal request that works and the request made from uploadify? E.g. are you requesting the script via the same hostname/subdomain?

Comment: See update please. I forgot to mention but the main thing that differs is **user-agent field** because other browsers doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Frode suggested in his comment I'm leaving this as an answer.

This can happen when using **any** flash script, not just uploadify. Any other flash uploader such as `SWFUpload` won't get the session unless user-agent field is the same.

This happens when your server has `suhosin` patch installed but it seems that sometimes this problem doesn't occur even when setting `suhosin.session.cryptua` is enabled as `alecgorge` suggested. Although I am not convinced about that. Of course you can pass to flash this variable using php scripts to uncover user-agent of user browser and then flash can disguise himself as the same browser but it's not elegant solution and I don't know actionscript so I can't say if flash can actually do it.

**Very important:**
There are actually **two** settings that can *fix* this security patch.

1. suhosin.session.encrypt
2. suhosin.session.cryptua

If the first one is disabled then session is not encrypted at all so problem won't occur. It's not recommended to disable this. If we disable only the second one then session will be encrypted but encryption won't relay on user-agent field. This means that any browser or http client can get any session. Therefore it's recommended to put some other security fields. Suhosin can handle also session ip protection so I recommend to enable `suhosin.session.cryptraddr`. Other settings can be found here:
[Suhosin configuration](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html)

To resolve this issue I suggest:

1. Check phpinfo() if suhosin is installed. If not then problem won't occur.
2. If suhosin is installed and `suhosin.session.cryptua` and `suhosin.session.encrypt` are enabled then copy existing and working php.ini. It's on the top of php info page: `Loaded Configuration File   /public_html/php5.ini`
3. Create your own php.ini and set:

   - suhosin.session.encrypt = On
   - suhosin.session.cryptraddr = On
   - suhosin.session.cryptua = Off

Comment: Please note using enabling suhosin.session.cryptraddr may break sessions for visitors behind some proxies (some corporate proxies balance the users connections [in a non-sticky fashion] among several proxy servers, each with a different IP).

Answer (score 0):

Usually with Uploadify I have to do something like this:

```
$('#uploadify').uploadify('scriptData':{'session_name':'<?php echo session_id(); ?>'}});
```

On the client in conjunction with something like this on the server side:

```
if($_POST['session_name']) {
    session_id($_POST['session_name']);
}
session_start();
```

Comment: Of course I send session id with uploadify parameters. Please read whole post and update. I think that suhosin is the case.

Comment: Oh I read the whole thing. It is just that this is a very common mistake and often when people think they have avoided this pitfall, they often fall right into it. Are sending the session as a get variable called PHPSESSID? Try calling it something else and posting like it did here. Then remove the things that scrape post get and cookie for PHPSESSID.

Comment: Also, I use this with on a server with `suhosin.session.cryptua` turned on and I have no problem.

Comment: Because other browsers can't get this session either. This must be suhosin. Then again I can't turn this off. As soon as i mess with htaccess the internal server error occurs. php.ini does not work at all.